# Why encoding needed in Database

Tags: database, encoding, compression

I have recently crossed the term `encoding`. I learned encoding is used to standardize different characters. Databases also encode data to standardize the table data. My question is If my column only contains decimal numbers still encoding is needed? , Is encoding have anything to do with the memory size of the data?.

Answer (score -1):

With the term *encoding*, we means putting a semantic value in a binary representation (binary: for most modern computer context; in theory encoding is nor restricted to computer bits/bytes).
The computers works differently than us, so we need to encode everything, so that computer can interpret the numbers. Sometime the encoding is implicit, or sometime outside CPU knowledge.

On a strict form of *encoding* (now out of fashion) when you decide the size of an integer (and whenever it is signed or unsigned), you are choosing (partially) an encoding (some part is still often implicit: type of representation of signed characters, endness of numbers, etc.). As long you are not reading the binary file of database, these doesn't matter much, but the size change the amount of memory/disk used. (note, we tend to call this type, not encoding, for numbers)

But as you see, now *encoding* is often used for strings (since tens of years we do care much about encoding for numbers). With this definition (and if you see "Unicode" or "UTF-8" or something similar, this mean that we are discussing just for string encoding), it doesn't matter the encoding of a number, but just the type.

But than there are locales (e.g. internationalization): you may need a specific encoding, so that e.g. thousand separator will be printed correctly, but this may be specified as locale/collation, or as database encoding, or in the client (which is the program in charge to display data).

So: for memory and disk (database engine side), the *encoding* (as string encoding) of a decimal and floats doesn't matter, just select the right type. For blobs and strings, the (string) encoding matter (but also for this case, you may need to check what are the available encodings on the engine: sometime the engine will use few encodings, and transform to other on software, so no changes on disk/memory).  Note: numbers are numbers, so it doesn't matter much, but for string, many SQL functions depends on encoding and locale (so on "server side", like `LIKE` keyword, sorting, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, but this answer has _some_ correct points but many incorrect as well. Encoding and internationalization have _some_ relation, but encoding doesn't have to do with thousand separators. In _programming_ we indeed talk about integral and floating point variable and member types, but when serializing or storing these types, we definitely encode them.

Comment: @CodeCaster: in i18n, locales defines also an encoding. You know, many time such character is outside ASCII. As far I read the question, serialization is outside scope (and also mostly as a client-server protocol, not a setting in database). I choose localisation, because often is more related (e.g. sorting), but all encoding issues are a can of worms. You can try to make an answer, but I think you will press "Add Answer" before even touching most of the topics (and it is also difficult to speak "databases" in generic term: these things are intimate to the specific engine).

Comment: @CodeCaster can you shed some lights on this topic?

Answer (score -3):

**Your first question:If column contains decimal numbers still encoding is needed?**

Answer : Columns in a table can and contain any data whether it is in form of decimal numbers or any other.
Every data no matter it is in which form either decimal,floating point,characters etc needs encoding to make it secure.Especially when you work with sensitive data or are looking for a way to organize your data in an archive you should consider encoding your data.

**Your second question:Is encoding have anything to do with the memory size of the data?.**

Answer : Since encoding removes redundancies from data, the size of your files will be a lot smaller. This results in faster input speed when data is saved.
Encoded data is smaller in size, you should be able to save space on your storage devices. This is ideal if you have large amounts of data that need to be archived.

Comment: This is wrong in so many ways that I don't even know where to start. Encoding is not encryption. Encoding doesn't make your files smaller, nor does encryption.